# Combining Dynamic Types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-typing

This might be a dumb question, but I'd love to know if there was a way I could do this.

To ease the process of importing lots and lots of Space-delimited files, I came up with a simple scheme to describe the layout in a dynamic type and throw it to a parser which calls a delegate.

A layout looks likes this:

```
var layout = new 
{
    Code = new SDFColumn() { Start = 0, Length = 20 },
    Name = new SDFColumn() { Start = 20, Length = 3 }
    // etc
};
```

All works great.  I'm now in a situation where I have 2 very large SDFs to import, whose structure is 85% identical, bar a few differences at the end.

Is there a way to append the layout of one to another, e.g:

```
var layoutCommon = new
{
     /* Common fields */
};

var layoutFile01 = new
{
     /* Changes for first file type */
};

var layoutFile02 = new
{
     /* Changes for the second file type */
};


var finalLayout = /* ??? */;
```

One thing I realised would not work, was:

```
var completeLayout = { };

if(file01)
    completeLayout = { /* everything */ };
else
    completeLayout = { /* everything */ };
```

This doesn't work, obviously, because all 3 types are fundamentally different.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: How about using inheritance? Put all common fields in a base class, and specific ones in the derived classes

Comment: @dano_ramos, I realise  could have just made a class for each layout, but the idea was to avoid doing that and just have the simplicity of defining a layout on the fly, within a function where I needed it, hence I went down this route.

Comment: Sounds more flexible, indeed. Now you got me interested

Comment: You could still have a common base class with the 'standard' layout details. Then override the relevant properties dynamically based on whichever layout type you're working with.

Comment: It's a more difficult problem than simply overriding properties. One file might have a header: "Name Date Employee", and another might have "Cat Dog Chicken TableSaw".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `dynamic` instead of `var`? That should delay typing until runtime, so your potential objects don't have to match. `var` is simply a substitute for any static type; it's not actually dynamic at all.

Comment: +1, Thanks for this.  I had actually used `dynamic` in the parser itself to allow the layout to be passed and interrogated using reflection.  I lose the advantage of the intellisense, but the layout is right in front of me anyway.  But this definitely solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: Yep, lack of intellisense is definitely a sad thing, but for now unavoidable. I actually did something much like this to handle a generic CSV structure, so it's nice to see someone else has the same idea!